# コマンドプロンプトから Python 3.6 スクリプトの実行時、input() でエラーになってしまう

Tags: python, python3, windows

Python3.6.2で以下の `input()` がエラーになります。

原因と修正方法をお教えください。

**実行環境:**
Windows 10
Python 3.6.5
(Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exeでインストールしました)

```
E:\work\python\lesson>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

test_inpStr.py をコマンドプロンプトから実行すると以下のエラーとなります。
何故でしょうか？

**test_inpStr.py**

```
#! python3                    
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-          
print("文字を入力してみよう。") 
x=input()                     
print(x,"が入力されたよ。")
```

**実行時のエラーメッセージ:**

```
E:\work\python\lesson>test_inpStr.py
文字を入力してみよう。
aaa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\work\python\lesson\test_inpStr.py", line 5, in ?
    x=input()
  File "<string>", line 0, in ?
NameError: name 'aaa' is not defined
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、おそらく Python 3 ではなく Python 2 で実行されているのではないかと思います。`python test_inpStr.py` という風に実行するとエラーが起きないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに2.4が入ってはいるんですが，環境変数「PATH」はanacondaの方に切ってあるので，一番上にある通り，「python」と入力すると，3.6.5とでできます。試してみましたが，以下の通りになりました。E:\work\python\lesson>python test_inpStr.py
  File "test_inpStr.py", line 4
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: 1行目の shebang `#! python3` を削除して `python test_inpStr.py` と実行してもうまくいきませんか？

Comment: 1行目を削除したら，次のようになりました。
File "test_inpStr.py", line 3
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: すいませんコメントの更新を追えていませんでした。shebang は関係ないですね。`python test_inpStr.py` と打つことでエラーが変わるのでしたら、やはり元々は Python 2 で実行されていたようです。回答として投稿してみます。

Comment: 参考: [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936078)

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.version)` という文を1行目あたりに仕込んで実行してみていただけますか？

Comment: 皆様いろいろありがとうございました！
使っていない2.4(それもライセンスが切れたソフトについていたpythonだったなんて!!)が動いていたのは驚きでした。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `x=input()` でのエラーについて

予想と反し、実際には Python 2 で実行していることが原因だと思われます。`python <ファイル名>` で実行するようにしてください。

コマンドプロンプト (cmd.exe) において `.py` で終わるファイル名のみを打ち込んだ場合、拡張子 `.py` に関連付けられたアプリケーションによってそのファイルが開かれます。今回の場合、コマンドプロンプトへ単に `test_inpStr.py` と打ち込んでいるため、関連付けられたアプリケーションによってスクリプトが解釈されています。出ているエラーから判断するに (※1)、おそらく以前どこかのタイミングで `.py` に Python 2 を関連付けており、Python 2 によってスクリプトが解釈されたのでしょう (※2)。

<sup>※1：[Python 3 と 2 では `input()` の挙動が異なり](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)、Python 2 における `input()` は入力を式として評価してしまうため、今回の NameError が出ます。</sup>

<sup>※2：[Shebang](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3_(Unix)) についてご存じであれば、「スクリプトファイル 1 行目の `#! python3` によって Python 3 になるのではないの？」と思うかもしれません。しかし shebang は主に UNIX 系のシェルにおける慣習であり、cmd.exe から直接実行する場合は意味がありません。Windows では[Python ランチャーを使っている場合に使われます](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yohhoy/20150320/p1)。</sup>

ファイルの関連付けを Python 3 へ変更したい場合、metropolis さんが[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48146/pyton3-6%E3%81%A7-input%E3%81%8C%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99/48147#comment49750_48146)なさった [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936078) をご覧ください。また本当に Python 2 で実行されているのか確かめたい場合、PicoSushi さんが[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48146/pyton3-6%E3%81%A7-input%E3%81%8C%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99/48147#comment49751_48146)なさっているように [`import sys; print(sys.version)`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/sys.html#sys.version) と書かれたスクリプトを実行するとバージョンが出力されます。

### Unicode error について

以下を確認してください。

- スクリプトファイルが utf-8 という文字コードで保存されているか。
- スクリプトに全角スペースが混じっていないか。

Answer (score 3):

### 解決しました

ご指摘の稼動しているpythonのバージョンを確認しました。

```
E:\work\python\lesson>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python24\\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

本来使いたいのは3.6ですので，コマンドプロンプト(管理者権限)でパスを通しました。
●管理者:コマンドプロンプト

```
C:\windows\system32>ftype Python.File="C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.File="C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

●コマンドプロンプト

```
E:\work\python\lesson>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

※パスを通す前に行ったこと([pythonランチャー](https://docs.python.jp/3/using/windows.html)で見つけた設定)
 - PATHEXT環境変数の拡張子リストに.PY;.PYWを追加
 - MAX_PATH の制限を除去
(ここでは不要だったかもしれません。)

1回エラーになり，test_inpStr.pyのエンコードを確認(shift-JISでした)，utf-8にしたところ，正常に動きました。

```
E:\work\python\lesson>test_inpStr.py
文字を入力してみよう。
aaa
aaa が入力されたよ。
```

ありがとうござました。

### 追伸

`import sys; print(sys.version)`を print_Version.py というファイルにして試してみました。

```
E:\work\python\lesson>print_Version.py
3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

```
E:\work\python\lesson>C:\Python24\\python print_Version.py
2.4.1 (#65, Mar 30 2005, 09:13:57) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
```